# Error in data pickle in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, nltk, pickle, naivebayes

I need to save my trainee data-set in data pickle. I used following code.

```
self.featureCounts = collections.defaultdict(lambda :0)
self.featureVectors = []
self.labelCounts = collections.defaultdict(lambda :0)

 def SaveOnPickle(self):
        f = open('dict.pickle', 'wb')
        pickle.dump(self.featureCounts, f)
        f.close()
```

When run this, there was following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/wamp64/www/M360/TrainClassifier.py", line 76, in <module>
    Predic.SaveOnPickle()
  File "C:/wamp64/www/M360/TrainClassifier.py", line 50, in SaveOnPickle
    pickle.dump(self.featureCounts, f)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1376, in dump
    Pickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 224, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 401, in save_reduce
    save(args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 568, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 754, in save_global
    (obj, module, name))
pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function <lambda> at 0x021391B0>: it's not found as __main__.<lambda>
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: [Pickling class instances](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Pickle

You can save your model like this :

```
import pickle
f = open('my_classifier.pickle', 'wb')
pickle.dump(classifier, f)
f.close()
```

and for loading later :

```
import pickle
f = open('my_classifier.pickle', 'rb')
classifier = pickle.load(f)
f.close()
```

Comment: I tried this code. But there was an error. I put it in the question How do i fix it?